# Uploading manifest with supportsCalling and supportsVideo fails with BadRequest

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I’m following these instructions to create a Teams calling bot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot

In my manifest.json, I have set supportsCalling and supportsVideo to true like this:

```
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "fa6ec2a6-XXXX",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "groupchat",
        "team"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsCalling": true,
      "supportsVideo": true
    }
  ],
```

When I use “upload custom app” in Teams, I get an error saying “Manifest parsing has failed”.
When I use “copy error details to clipboard”, all I get is this:
Bad Request

If I remove supportsCalling and supportsVideo from the manifest, I am able to upload it with no errors.

I have followed the instructions to enable calling on the Teams channel and added all the Microsoft Graph permissions, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting manifestVersion to devPreview fixed the problem.

Comment: What's devPreview and where can I find it? I have the same issue.